# How can I redirect all output to system.log to my own log?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, exception

So I already rolled my own custom logging function, which works quite well.  But error messages are still being printed to system.log.

I've been googling around a bit and I've seen mentions of redirected stderr, but I haven't actually seen any examples on how to do this.  Does anyone have any insight into how I can achieve this?  (And is simply closing the stderr file descriptor + re-opening it the solution?)

I want to be capturing messages like "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15a918a0" etc...

Comment: *may* have just answered my own question, can anyone verify?  You use:  freopen(myLogFile,"a+",stderr);

Comment: I haven't tested it, but I think you might be on the right track - I clicked on the question intending to suggest freopen() if no one else had. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

freopen(myLogFile,"a+",stderr);